# Find lower left corner of a rotated polygon

Tags: arcpy, polygon, vertices, angles

I am currently struggling with a mathematical problem and can't seem to get it solved.

I have a bunch of rotated rectangular polygons (solution should also work for non-rectangular polygons) in different shapefiles. I want to (automatically) find the lower left corner of each of the polygons using python (arcpy).

First I tried to simply use the extent, but since they are rotated, the extent will bring false results. So how do I approach this? I googled for hours and the only thing I could come up with, is to somehow calculate the center of the polygon or somehow temporairly rotate it to 180 degrees and then use xmin and ymin. Here are a few pictures which may help to distract the attention from my bad english (sorry for that btw)

[image] [image]

I had no problems exporting the coordinates of the polygons by using the feature vertices to points tool. So far I extracted them once in a list of tupels and once in two different lists (one for x-coords and one for y-coords)

so here are a few coordinates to make it easier to test:

**tupel-format:**

```
tupelList=[[1792398.680577231, 4782539.85121522],
 [1792173.0363913027, 4780368.293228334],
 [1788935.7990357098, 4780713.732859781],
 [1789162.9530321995, 4782885.332685629],
 [1792398.680577231, 4782539.85121522]]
```

**x-list/y-list format:**

```
xList= [1792398.680577231, 1792173.0363913027, 1788935.7990357098, 1789162.9530321995, 1792398.680577231]

yList=[4782539.85121522, 4780368.293228334, 4780713.732859781, 4782885.332685629, 4782539.85121522]
```

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.3.1 width ally extensions and an advanced license. Version of Python is 2.7.something

Comment: Hmmm, take the extent, then find the vertex that's closest to the southwest corner of the extent? What vertex do you want if the polygon is V shaped?

Comment: Have a look at this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/determining-y-coordinate-for-create-fishnet-from-desired-angle-of-rotation-in-py/121741#121741  It uses convex hull and rotation angle. I guess it's a good starting point for you. It's tuple anyway...

Comment: Even though you talk primarily about rectangles I think you should edit your question to show examples of what you mean by "non-rectangular" as this will dictate the solution

Comment: @mkennedy this won't work for some polygons like parallelograms--> see a picture here (couldn't post more than two links, because I'm new here) http://oi67.tinypic.com/33wrytw.jpg (the brownish stuff is supposed to be the extent)

Comment: @Hornbydd The polygons could as well be parallelograms or even non-symetrial polygons with four corners. I don't understand what difference it would make for the solution though

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very simple approach that offloads all the processing into the [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm#GUID-26359B3D-A0C8-4666-B99B-40C8B4D91449) GP tool. Since you have access to an Advanced license, sorting by shape and starting at the lower left corner gives quick results.

```py
import os, arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inFC = r'<path>'
outFC = r'<path>'

# create output FC to hold points and field to link OID
spatref = arcpy.Describe(inFC).spatialReference
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(*os.path.split(outFC), geometry_type="POINT",
                                    spatial_reference=spatref)
arcpy.AddField_management(outFC, "ID", "LONG")


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFC, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as sCursor:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["ID", "SHAPE@"]) as iCursor:
        for oid, poly in sCursor:

            # using Geometry objects is very quick and also has the added
            # benefit of returning lists of geometries
            # Since we are sorting the vertices by LL, the first one is the answer
            verts = arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(poly, arcpy.Geometry())
            sort = arcpy.Sort_management(verts, arcpy.Geometry(),
                                         [["SHAPE", "ASCENDING"]], "LL")[0]
            iCursor.insertRow([oid, sort])
```

[image]

From the explanation on [spatial sorting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/how-sort-works.htm), we see that N/S takes precedence over E/W:

> Note that U gets priority over R. R is taken into considerations only
>   when some features are at the same horizontal level.

Comment: Cool use of `arcpy.Geometry()` in `arcpy.Sort_management`.

Answer (score 4):

Given the examples of the rectangles and parallelograms, and if I'm understanding your formulation of "lower-left" (i.e., "the most south-west") correctly, a naive solution:

You could sort the four vertices in order of ascending latitude(i.e., the south-most is first, north-most is last). If two are equal in latitude, their sequence doesn't matter. Then, among the two south-most points, select the one that is further west. This would give you the green-dotted corners in this illustration:

[image]

The following might be rare or non-existent cases, but the above falls apart with a quadrilateral where the two vertices between the south-most and north-most are of equal latitude, such as a "diamond" shape, or some deformation of it, or even when a perfect rectangle is rotated just so:

[image]

To deal robustly with these cases, you could use an approach that calculates the medial axis of the shape (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis), compares it's slope to 45 and 135 degrees, and determines the "bottom" and "top" of the shape compared to that. Then progress as above, with the west-most point of the two "bottom" points being the point to choose. That would work in two of the above illustrated cases. It would still fail in the case of a perfect square in "diamond" rotation - but then there's no "natural" bottom-left corner to that shape. Another way to deal with these cases where points 2 and 3 in the vertical sequence are at equal latitude is to actually take point 1, the south-most point; or the west-most point among 2 and 3.