# Creating 1 hectare rectangle polygon surrounding points and dividing it into equal sized sub-quadrats in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, features

I have a set of points like this:

[image]]

I have only these points' information. Now I want to draw a boundary of this points whose size should be 1 hectare (100m x 100m). After that, I want to subdivide this area into 16 equal quadrats like this: Each side of subplots should be (25m x 25m).

[image]

How can I do this in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Create minimum bounding rectangle, extend to your dimensions and move slightly. Use this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/determining-y-coordinate-for-create-fishnet-from-desired-angle-of-rotation-using?r=SearchResults after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way would be to use the [Grid Index Features](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) tool to create a rectangle of the size you need and divide it into the quadrants you like.

Adjust the parameters polygon_width and polygon_height to match your need (1 hectare) and number_rows and number_columns as well (16).
[image]

Of course then you'll need to move the resulting layer by hand with the traditional move and rotate tools in the editor toolbar, but this would be one good way to go IMO.

[image]

Comment: @ Umbe1987. Thank you so much. It is an amazing work!

Comment: @514143 You're very welcome, happy to have helped you. If my answer solved your problem, would you mind accepting it?