# Sub-dividing oriented polygon grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have a grid of squares which are not aligned N-S, E-W.

These are 5m squares, but I've been asked to reduce these to 1m squares.

Therefore I need to sub-divide one square into 25 squares on the same grid orientation as the 5m square.

I have access to ArcMap.

Below is an example, showing the 5m sqaures split into 9 sub divisions.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Pick either ArcMap or QGIS or your question might get closed (pick QGIS). Probably easier to create a new 1 m grid and join your data to it

Comment: This is pretty easy with ArcPy (dirt easy if the polygons are really quadrilaterals), but you need to choose a stack first.

Comment: They look like perfect squares, area is 25.00001 to 24.99995 I assume because the grid was rotated. Despite preferring open source, let's go with ArcMap as the focus.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/determining-y-coordinate-for-create-fishnet-from-desired-angle-of-rotation-using/121741#121741