# Rotate a fishnet in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid

I have created a fishnet of sampling points within the area defined by the polygon shown below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLIqZ.jpg). The grid is unrotated but I want to rotate it so the lines of points run parallel to the length of the site (i.e. SW-NE instead of W-E).

The current settings are shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLje0.jpg) and I know I need to change the y-axis co-ordinates but I cannot figure out how to work out what they should be changed to! Any ideas?

[image: Unrotated Fishnet Grid]

[image: Unrotated Fishnet Settings]

Comment: Change the Y axis coordinate parameter. You'll need to determine the correct angle and compute the corresponding point. Note that there are an infinite number of suitable points (it defines a line, after all), so just choose a distance and compute the X & Y at that distance -- soh-cah-toa.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/determining-y-coordinate-for-create-fishnet-from-desired-angle-of-rotation-using#121633

Comment: The [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) works an example of rotation. At least give it a try.